# textarea into array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

myList contains the following values:

> value1
>   value2
>   value3

```
function showArray() {
  var txt = $("#myList").text();
  var textread = txt.split('\n');

  var msg = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < textread .length; i++) {
    msg += i + ": " + textread [i] + "\n";
  }
  alert(msg);
}
```

my alert gives me the following:

> 0:value1
>   value2
>   value3

It`s not what I wanted and expecting, I was expecting something like:

> 0: value1
>   1: value2
>   2: value3

How can I get the values as expected?

Comment: looks like textread.length==1; could you ouput that too and tell the value here ?

Comment: Have I tweaked your question correctly or does the first alert show all values on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with a `textarea` and it pretty much worked.

The only thing I changed was `var txt = $("#myList").text();` to `var txt = $("#myList").val();`.

Comment: This works because val() preserves the white space in the textarea, while text() doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with the character used as line break...